# How to do file inputs for Active Storage on a front end?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, file-upload, rails-activestorage

Hi guys I have a Rails Backend and React front end Im trying to do Active storage to implement image uploads. I have been following along with instruction given in this article https://pragmaticstudio.com/tutorials/using-active-storage-in-rails .Everything was going smoothly until the subject Upload an Image came "The model is now ready to accept an image attachment. To let users choose a file to upload from their computer, we need a form which includes a file upload input field, like so:"

```
<%= f.label :main_image %>
<%= f.file_field :main_image %>
```

I have no idea where this goes whether on the front end form or backend..And also how to write it when I try to add this in My react form It throws and error identifier expected ..
Here is my code on front end

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";



function AddReviewForm({user,handleAddReviews}){
    const params = useParams();
   const[img,setImg]=useState("");
   const[r,setR]=useState("")
      const newReview = {
        img,
        r,
        restaurant_id: params.id,
        user_id: user.id,
      };
      const configObj = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(newReview),
      };


      // function handleReviewChange(event) {
      //   setreviewData({
      //     ...reviewData,
      //     [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
      //   });
      // }
      function handleReviewSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        fetch(`/reviews`, configObj)
          .then((r) => r.json())
          .then((review)=>{
            handleAddReviews(review);
            setR('')
            setImg('')
            
          }
          );
      }
      
    return  (
        <>
        <h1>Add review form</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleReviewSubmit}>
          <div>
        <%= f.label :main_image >
        <%= f.file_field :main_image %>   


          </div>
       <div>
        <label htmlFor="img"  >Image</label>
         <input type="text" name="img"   value={img}  onChange={(e) => setImg(e.target.value)} placeholder="name" />
       </div>
       <div>
        <label htmlFor="r"  >Review</label>
         <input type="text" name="r"   value={r}  onChange={(e) => setR(e.target.value)} placeholder="review" />
      </div>
       <input type="submit" />

        </form>
        </>
    )
}
export default AddReviewForm;
```

Also my Review model which has one image attached

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :restaurant
  has_one_attached :main_image

  validates :r, length: { maximum: 1000,
  too_long: "%{1000} characters is the maximum allowed" }
end
```

Check out Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's ERB syntax. It will not work in React

Please look docs for [`file_field`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-file_field) and [`label`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-label). There you will find HTML examples generated by these helpers

You need something like

```html
<label htmlFor="main_image">Add image</label>
<input type="file" name="review[main_image]" id="main_image" />
```

And also add some React logics for file upload and form submit processing

There is also [Directs Upload](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/active_storage_overview.html#direct-uploads). It is another way to use ActiveStorage